# goLang. call ".Front()" for a string list. But returns error saying string list has no Front method

Tags: go

I have code like this

```
t := strings.FieldsFunc(value, extract_word)
        fmt.Println("t:", len(t),t)
        m := make(map[string]int)
    for word := t.Front(); word != nil; word=word.Next(){
            m[word]++   
    }
```

and it gets this error

```
t.Front undefined (type []string has no field or method Front)
```

I know list has Front() method.
http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/
but why it complains here?
so confused, need help.
thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]T` is not a "list" as it's referred to in other languages (e.g. Python). In Go, it's referred to as the "Slice" http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types

Its elements range from `0` to `len(slice)-1`, and are accessed with C-like array access notation. The "front" of the slice is generally considered `slice[0]`, though you may consider a different index the front if you're using a slice to implement something like, e.g., a stack.

No built-in type in Go has any methods defined on it, but do have [built-in functions](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/) that take them as arguments, such as `len`.

The package you linked to implements the `List` type. As the documentation at the top says "Package list implements a doubly linked list." This doubly linked list, which you can create by calling `list.New()`, has a `Front` method, among the others listed in the package documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`t` is not a `List`. It is a slice of strings (slices and Lists are not the same thing). The first element of a slice is `[0]`.

I believe the `for` loop you mean is this (untested):

```
for _, word := range t {
    m[word]++   
}
```